# How to reset Angular form when login fails

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

I need to reset some inputs that I use to store the login PIN from a user, I have a service that generate a modal with an error message, and I'm able to clean the user name field, but not the inputs that I use to store de PIN, which are under the #inputs id. Please check my code below.

**HTML**

```
      <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginForm" ngNaviteValidate #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logIn(); loginForm.reset()">
    <a class="text-center db"><img src="../assets/images/LOGO.png" style="width: 52%;" alt="Home" /></a>
    <div class="form-group m-t-40">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h4>USUARIO</h4>
          <input class="form-control" id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" [(ngModel)]="login.username"
          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
      <br>
      <br>
             <h4>PIN</h4>
          <div class="inputs form-control" id="inputs">
            <input maxlength="2" placeholder="•" value="" type="password" id="pinOne" [(ngModel)]="password[0]"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            <input maxlength="2" placeholder="•" value="" type="password" id="pinTwo" [(ngModel)]="password[1]"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            <input maxlength="2" placeholder="•" value="" type="password" id="pinThree" [(ngModel)]="password[2]"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            <input maxlength="2" placeholder="•" value="" type="password" id="pinFour" [(ngModel)]="password[3]"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            <input maxlength="2" placeholder="•" value="" type="password" id="pinFive" [(ngModel)]="password[4]"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            <input maxlength="1" placeholder="•" value="" type="password" id="pinSix" [(ngModel)]="password[5]"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-md btn-block text-uppercase btn-rounded"
          type="submit">Ingresar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  logIn() {
this.login.password = this.concatPassword(this.password);
this.authService.login(this.login)
.subscribe(res => {
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This clean the username but not the PIN
    this.login.username = '';
    this.login.password = '';
    this.password = [];
  } else {
    this.messageWelcome(res.user);
  }
})
```

}

How should I reset those input fields?

Comment: I don't get your question correctly do you want to save the password or just reset all form values in that what you want just use `resetForm` method

Comment: I want to reset the form, if the user/PIN is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use NgForm `resetForm` method to reset the form value and this will reset all form elements.

```js
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

...

@ViewChild("form") form: NgForm; // get reference of the NgForm directive

logIn() {
 // const tempPass = this.password; 
 this.login.password = this.concatPassword(this.password);
 this.authService.login(this.login)
 .subscribe(res => {
   if (!res.ok) {
    this.from.resetForm(); //
    // you don't need to reset the login manually  
    // this.login.username = ''; 
    // this.login.password = '';
    // this.password = []; 
  } else {
    this.messageWelcome(res.user);
  }
});
}
```

> you need to remove this option `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` and set the name attribute

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7k5sp)

Comment: @NullEins happy to help 